# Restrict Memory Usage per Worker Node in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I would like to restrict memory usage in each workernodes in my Storm multi node cluster. for eg  in a worker node of 512mb ram , i want storm to use max upto 256mb .

> `worker.childopts: "-Xmx256m"`

As per my understanding above configuration is for setting memory for each worker processes in a node.
 Is there a way i can restrict memory as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory used by storm is `number of slots` times `worker memory` plus `supervisor memory`. So if you have one worker slot defined, worker.childopts set to `-Xmx256m`, and supervisor.childopts set to -Xmx128m then each storm worker node will take up a max of 384mb per node.

Comment: thankyou for the  help. one more doubt by setting are we limiting only worker processes memory or is it supervisor + worker process = 256m (Max)

Comment: Good point. You probably need to account for the supervisor memory as well.

Comment: could you please guide how to set for supervisor as well

Comment: I edited my answer to include the setting for the supervisors which is supervisor.childopts